# Sphinx search relevancy. Ranking, ordering, weight, keyword order

Tags: search, sphinx

I'm experiencing problems with relevance in Sphinx. I have a fairly easy out-of-the-box setup using SphinxQL, nothing fancy. My database has around 300k documents. Default ranking mode.

Search query is, for example: "apple imac pro" (apple|imac|pro).

**The result contains the following:**

1 apple imac ...
2 apple imac ...
3-20. apple pro ...

Now, of course there is no such thing as an "apple imac pro" in my database, but why does it skip to "apple pro" results, when there are more "apple imac" and/or "imac apple" results? Why does it skip to the "pro" part if "imac" is closer to the beginning of the line in the original search query?

Does the order of keywords in the field affect the order/weight THAT much?

**My expectation for the result would be:**

1. Show all "apple imac pro" - there are none
2. Show all "apple imac" or "imac apple" items
3. Show all "apple pro" or "pro apple" items / show all "imac pro" or "pro imac" items
4. Show all "apple" or "imac" or "pro" items

This sort of thing seemed much easier to accomplish with the MySQL Full Text Search. The results would be much closer to what I expect, than what Sphinx gives me.

I've tried changing the ranking mode to sph04, with no avail.

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Is there anything I can do to "fix" this?

Thanks in advance.